# How i can access to Map methods in visualforce page

Tags: apex, map, visualforce

Hello I'm a beginner in Salesforce and i have to access to Size method of a Map but I need access in my VFP, the controller is:

```
variable = new Map<string,Map<string,boolean>>();
variable.put('keytext', previousMapCreated);
```

And my VFP

```
<apex:column rendered = "{!variable.values.size>=8}">
  ...... some code...........
</apex:column>
```

When I run the code i Got this error
**Map key values.size not found in map**
Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a variable to store the size in your controller?

```
variable = new Map<string,Map<string,boolean>>();
variable.put('keytext', previousMapCreated);
Integer theSize = variable.values().size();

<apex:column rendered = "{!theSize>=8}">
  ...... some code...........
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Sorry but i need the size of inside Map, a variable does not solve it, because external map size is variable